# Lync SDK Basic usage - memory leaking?

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

I've recently launched an application that interacts with Lync Clients using Lync SDK (both 2010 and 2013)

It seems to me I've done something very wrong, because once I'm attached to the Lync SDK, the process memory starts growing without any limit. I wrote a basic test application to debug this, but the memory still seems to be leaking. The process used memory grows by 100-300 KB for every conversation added - even though i do not even subscribe to any Lync events. I doubt this leak has a limit, bug I stopped checking at ~120MB

Call to the .NET Garbage Collector does not seem to solve this.

Here is the code I am using to test this:

```
class Program
{
    static LyncClient _LyncClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _LyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above code leaks once conversations start in the Lync client, even though I am not registered to any of the events.

(This is a near-repost of the question I asked on the [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a27818e-dc5a-407f-afad-d5814360fef2/lync-sdk-memory-leak?forum=communicatorsdk), with no answer )

Comment: I can confirm that it does appear to be leaking memory, a few hundred k per IM call, in the Lync.exe process.  The somewhat woeful documentation doesn't seem to acknowledge this, or prescribe any remedy that I've seen thus far.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?